# bicep definition with palm facing out (using dumbbells)

Tags: dumbbells, biceps

I recently started weight training with dumbbells only. My biceps definition with palms facing in are coming along nicely when I fold my arms but they are flat when palms are facing out or parallel to my torso.

What exercises can I do with dumbbells to build bicep definition with palms facing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To develop good biceps definition, in your case, as I guess, you need:

1. Combine exercies hitting *biceps* with one which hitting
   *brachialis* (here you can find the [list](http://www.exrx.net/Lists/ExList/ArmWt.html#Biceps) at the bottom of the pages). As example, I do hammer curls and parallel pull ups
2. You should also focus on hitting big muscle groups during your
   workout - that way muscles are growing better (and during workout
   better first do your chest/back/legs and then bicpes/triceps, its
   smaller groups)
3. Patience - keep working out and you will se results in a while

Comment: Danil, thanks again for your response. It's been a few months since I posted this question and I am starting to see results. Probably slower than the hardcore lifters but they are coming along. :)

Comment: Oh, you're welcome! Cool, good to know that it helped :)